# "Empty solution not allowed" captcha error when user tries to register

Tags: joomla-4.x, update, captcha

I've just updated my site from 3.x to 4.2.6 and now users started getting error "Empty solution not allowed". I was digging a bit and I found that this error is from Captcha (PLG_RECAPTCHA_INVISIBLE_ERROR_EMPTY_SOLUTION). It was super hard to find out because the error is displayed only sometimes.

I found some answer that it is caused by conflicting captchas, like here:
https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/forum/91506-i-get-an-warning-empty-solution-not-allowed-after-updating-to-joomla-4-7

But when I check my site settings, it is all okay according to this guide:
https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Google_ReCaptcha

In global settings, invisible captcha is set.
In users settings, global setting is applied.
In contacts settings, global settings is applied.
In plugins, two captchas are installed (captcha - reCaptcha, captcha - Invisible reCaptcha), but only Invisible reCaptcha is enabled.

I am confident, that it worked on 3.x.

In the header, I can see that these three scripts regarding captcha are loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/releases/5qcenVbrhOy8zihcc2aHOWD4/recaptcha__cs.js" crossorigin="anonymous" integrity="sha384-RA/l2XGNJ+Rr18sma+5V4vZQ7+05NfsdC/fNwQDzVwQA9Au8wVyKKP0Pax1D1eol"></script>
<script src="/media/plg_captcha_recaptcha_invisible/js/recaptcha.min.js?b63a9703436effa4bcce99245487800f" defer=""></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=JoomlainitReCaptchaInvisible&amp;render=explicit&amp;hl=cs-CZ" defer=""></script>
```

Then right after the register form, there are these two divs (I believe here is the conflict):

```
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1" class="class=&quot;g-recaptcha required&quot; g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="6LcoRLUaAAAAANZBMsFahpm9TpHB84usZJR0cdta" data-badge="bottomleft" data-size="invisible"
    data-tabindex="0" data-callback="" data-expired-callback="" data-error-callback="" data-recaptcha-widget-id="0">
    <div class="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="bottomleft"
        style="width: 256px; height: 60px; display: block; transition: left 0.3s ease 0s; position: fixed; bottom: 14px; left: -186px; box-shadow: gray 0px 0px 5px; border-radius: 2px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div class="grecaptcha-logo"><iframe title="reCAPTCHA"
                src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LcoRLUaAAAAANZBMsFahpm9TpHB84usZJR0cdta&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2tsYWRvbGVqdS5jejo0NDM.&amp;hl=cs&amp;v=5qcenVbrhOy8zihcc2aHOWD4&amp;size=invisible&amp;badge=bottomleft&amp;cb=h5hy3b2wbqg5"
                width="256" height="60" role="presentation" name="a-g64gyyt7qyqo" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
                sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="grecaptcha-error"></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response" name="g-recaptcha-response"
            class="g-recaptcha-response"
            style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="dynamic_recaptcha_1" class="class=&quot;g-recaptcha required&quot; g-recaptcha"
    data-sitekey="6LcoRLUaAAAAANZBMsFahpm9TpHB84usZJR0cdta" data-badge="bottomleft" data-size="invisible"
    data-tabindex="0" data-callback="" data-expired-callback="" data-error-callback="" data-recaptcha-widget-id="1">
    <div class="grecaptcha-badge" data-style="none"
        style="width: 256px; height: 60px; position: fixed; visibility: hidden;">
        <div class="grecaptcha-logo"><iframe title="reCAPTCHA"
                src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?ar=1&amp;k=6LcoRLUaAAAAANZBMsFahpm9TpHB84usZJR0cdta&amp;co=aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cuc2tsYWRvbGVqdS5jejo0NDM.&amp;hl=cs&amp;v=5qcenVbrhOy8zihcc2aHOWD4&amp;size=invisible&amp;badge=bottomleft&amp;cb=q41x4whykroe"
                width="256" height="60" role="presentation" name="a-wbuyh3o4dc14" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
                sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="grecaptcha-error"></div><textarea id="g-recaptcha-response-1" name="g-recaptcha-response"
            class="g-recaptcha-response"
            style="width: 250px; height: 40px; border: 1px solid rgb(193, 193, 193); margin: 10px 25px; padding: 0px; resize: none; display: none;"></textarea>
    </div><iframe style="display: none;"></iframe>
</div>
```

And at the bottom of this page, there are another two captchas (again, only one should be here, right?):

```
<div
    style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; top: -10000px; left: 0px; right: 0px; transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear 0s; opacity: 0;">
    <div
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.5;">
    </div>
    <div
        style="margin: 0px auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); z-index: 2000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe title="ověření recaptcha vyprší za dvě minuty"
            src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=cs&amp;v=5qcenVbrhOy8zihcc2aHOWD4&amp;k=6LcoRLUaAAAAANZBMsFahpm9TpHB84usZJR0cdta"
            name="c-g64gyyt7qyqo" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>
</div>
<div
    style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; width: 100%; top: -10000px; left: 0px; right: 0px; transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s linear 0s; opacity: 0;">
    <div
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: fixed; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 2000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); opacity: 0.5;">
    </div>
    <div
        style="margin: 0px auto; top: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; position: absolute; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); z-index: 2000000000; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden;">
        <iframe title="ověření recaptcha vyprší za dvě minuty"
            src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/bframe?hl=cs&amp;v=5qcenVbrhOy8zihcc2aHOWD4&amp;k=6LcoRLUaAAAAANZBMsFahpm9TpHB84usZJR0cdta"
            name="c-wbuyh3o4dc14" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"
            sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

When I hit register now, the error is displayed.